# Use array as bind variable Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Snowflake  scripting I need to bind the input parameter of the stored procedure which is an array and it will be part of array_contains function in dynamic sql however its throwing bind error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use ARRAY data type as a bind argument inside Snowflake Scripting:

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(i INT, j TEXT);

INSERT INTO t(i, j) VALUES (1,'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd');
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_array_arg(ARG ARRAY)
RETURNS TABLE(i INT, j TEXT)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
   res RESULTSET default (SELECT i, j 
                          FROM t 
                          WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(t.i::VARIANT, :ARG));
BEGIN
    RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
$$;
```

Procedure call:

```
CALL sp_array_arg([1,3]);
/*
I   J
1   a
3   c
*/
```